# How to count unique values across two columns with certain types in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got data feeding into a database like below.

Now I can use a single query many times to achieve this but I'm looking for a way to query once and return all results.

Time, ID (the totally unique column), ReqType (can be 1 value out of 30), ReqName (can be 1 out of 20).

| time | ID | ReQtype | ReqName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1345 | 12 | 1 | test |
| 1346 | 13 | 2 | test |
| 1352 | 14 | 1 | hello world |
| 1352 | 15 | 3 | fith |
| 1354 | 16 | 1 | hello world |
| 1357 | 17 | 4 | apple |

Without constructing a query for every variable of ReqType and ReqName I would like to return in X time (last 30min for example above) (this will be two queries actually I think)

| count | ReqName |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | test |
| 2 | hello world |
| 1 | fith |
| 1 | apple |

| Count | ReqType |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |

Comment: It can be one query, but `ReqType` and `ReqName` must be the same data type so   `ReqType` would have to be convert form int to text. How do the values in the `time` column relate to "last 30 minutes"? Is `time` the time of day, so `'1345'` means `13:45`? If so, how do you distinguish `1345` today from `1345` yesterday. Please explain.

Comment: Why do you want `3` for `test`'s count? As the two result sets are fundamentally different, why are you trying to avoid doing this in two queries? What's the relevance of "last 30mins"? (You only have an integer column, not a date or timestamp datatype column.)

Comment: So Reqtype is a number value and ReqName is always text, the time field is fully in sql format 'year/month/day hour/min/sec/ms' 
just used hours and mins for example.



I am aware that to get the bottom two tables will require two queries. (hopefully)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can achieve something closer to it within single query like this:

```
SELECT
    ReqName,
    ReqType,
    COUNT(*) AS count
FROM public.carrier
WHERE created_at BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '30 minutes' AND NOW()
GROUP BY
    GROUPING SETS (
    (ReqName),
    (ReqType) )
```

This will first group by ReqName and then group by ReqType. Later show them in a single table.

| ReqName | ReqType | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| test | NULL | 2 |
| hello world | NULL | 2 |
| fith | NULL | 1 |
| apple | NULL | 1 |
| NULL | 1 | 3 |
| NULL | 2 | 1 |
| NULL | 3 | 1 |
| NULL | 4 | 1 |